# What happened to SE? Sometimes it doesn't show up-vote points notification and sometimes 1 month ago activity show up in RSS reader!

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications, feed

What happened to SE? Sometimes it doesn't show upvote points notification.

And now I received an RSS notification of a user. When I opened it, I saw that the comment/answer was posted in 2019 and has not been edited recently. what is the problem?

**Update 1:** The following screenshot illustrates another problem in upvote points notification. (my post has been up-voted twice but in notification total points are 28 for my post!!)
[image]

**Update 2 (may 13, 2020):** Yesterday and today I earned 20 points for my old posts but without any notification. Here are my posts has been up-voted: [TSE post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473140/how-to-add-patterns-inside-shapes-bounded-by-curves) and [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3681460/non-trivial-bbb-tk-action-and-generalized-killing-vector-fields)

**Update 3 (September 27 2020):** The problem has gotten worse I think. The following is the today reputations:

[image]

The reputation (+8) is incorrect and it must be (+10) instead of (+12), since the (+2) rep has been rewarded 3 hours ago but without notification.

---

**Update 4 (Nov 23, 2020):**  I just realized that RSS feeds pops up when the user I follow him, has an activity on a post, but now the RSS notification popped up when I edited a post that an user that I follow him commented to that post 7 hours ago (i.e. I received two RSS feeds, one for comment 7hours ago and one for editing now). (I am talking about [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3918660/272127))

Comment: First problem is for days ago and I don't remember which one. second problem the user name of linked RSS suffices or you want the exact post has been notified?

Comment: The RSS opened [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436971/compact-boundary-of-non-compact-manifold/3436975#3436975) for me.

Comment: It's possibly a problem with your RSS reader software

Comment: My RSS reader is https://feeder.co/. Isn't good one?

Comment: I don't know if it's good or not but it could be due to the third party software. About your update: can you click on the score to see exactly how many upvotes you got? Since you have more than 2k rep you can click the score to see the vote distribution. You might have actually received 3 upvotes and one downvote which gives you a net gain of 28 (+30 for 3 upvotes -2 for 1 downvote)

Comment: That you don't get notifications for upvotes in your topbar might be due to this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348030/random-pages-across-se-feel-dead-due-to-se-websocket-misbehaving-sometimes-c

Comment: Check if you have different sites that got downvotes. They don't show up in that list if that is the only activity for a site, but do affect the total rep.

Comment: I have checked Reputations tab of all sites, I did not find any negative rep. there!

Comment: It is odd a bit, why +8 in notification bar? see both screen shots!!

Comment: Is it possible to see what are the source codes of notification of SE?

Comment: Another reason for less reputation being shown is that you downvoted some posts.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about two separate topics. The notifcations and the RSS feed. Please make questions concise and un-ambiguous.

Comment: @Luuklag Then you should vote to close it as "needs more focus". Closing it as "other" will mark it as "not about Stack Exchange". You can always post a comment manually if you want to clarify why you voted to close, but you should avoid using custom close reasons unless the question actually has nothing to do with Stack Exchange.